# How to send 50.000 HTTP requests in a few seconds?

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, load-testing

I want to create a load test for a feature of my app. It’s using a Google App Engine and a VM. The user sends HTTP requests to the App Engine. It’s realistic that this Engine gets thousands of requests in a few seconds. So I want to create a load test, where I send 20.000 - 50.000 in a timeframe of 1-10 seconds.

How would you solve this problem?

I started to try using Google Cloud Task, because it seems perfect for this. You schedule HTTP requests for a specific timepoint. The docs say that there is a limit of 500 tasks per second per queue. If you need more tasks per second, you can split this tasks into multiple queues. I did this, but Google Cloud Tasks does not execute all the scheduled task at the given timepoint. One queue needs 2-5 minutes to execute 500 requests, which are all scheduled for the same second :thinking_face:

I also tried a TypeScript script running asynchronous `node-fetch` requests, but I need for 5.000 requests 77 seconds on my macbook.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get 50.000 HTTP requests "in a few seconds" from "your macbook", it's better to consider going for a special load testing tool (which can be deployed onto [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/) virtual machine in order to minimize [network latency](https://www.tatatelebusiness.com/articles/what-is-network-latency-and-what-does-it-mean-to-me) and traffic costs)

The tool choice is up to you, either you need to have powerful enough [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) so it would be able to conduct 50k requests "in a few seconds" from a single virtual machine or the tool needs to have the feature of running in [clustered mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) so you could kick off several machines and they would send the requests together at the same moment of time.

Given you mention TypeScript you might want to try out [k6 tool](https://k6.io/) (it doesn't scale though) or check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) to see what are other options, none of them provides JavaScript API however several don't require programming languages knowledge at all

Answer (score 0):

A tool you could consider using is [siege](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/load-testing-with-siege/).

This is [Linux based](https://linux.die.net/man/1/siege) and to prevent any additional cost by testing from an outside system out of GCP.

You could deploy siege on a [relatively large machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#recommendations_for_machine_types) or a few machines inside GCP.

It is fairly simple to set up, but since you mention that you need 20-50k in a span of a few seconds, siege by default only allows 255 requests per second. [You can make this larger](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/http-load-testing-siege/), though, so it can fit your needs.

You would need to play around on how many connections a machine can establish, since each machine will have a certain limit based on CPU, Memory and number of network sockets. You could just increase the -c number, until the machine gives an "Error: system resources exhausted" error or something similar. Experiment with what your virtual machine on GCP can handle.